# *Resolved* Pine Script mismatched input, expecting 'end of line without line continuation'

Tags: pine-script, bitcoin, algorithmic-trading, trading, mismatch

I'm trying to code a trading strategy in pine script. I just have a little problem in my code at line 100:

*line 100: Mismatched input 'strategy.entry' expecting 'end of line without line continuation'*

I tryed to search by my own but found nothing it's the reason why I'm asking here. By the way, I'm in version 4 of pine script.

````
buytrend = 0

if supertrend == 1 and supertrend2 == 1
    buytrend = 1
else if supertrend3 == 1 and supertrend == 1
    buytrend = 1
if supertrend2 == 1 and supertrend3 == 1
    buytrend = 1

if supertrend == -1 and supertrend2 == -1
    buytrend = 0
else if supertrend3 == -1 and supertrend == -1
    buytrend = 0
if supertrend2 == -1 and supertrend3 == -1
    buytrend = 0


//plot marketprice

marketprice = ema(close,1)
plot(marketprice,"Marketprice",color.yellow)

//signals

Buysignal = crossover(k, d) and k < 20 and marketprice > ema and buytrend == 1
Sellsignal = crossunder(k, d)
Sellsignal2 = if buytrend == 0

//strategy

strategy.entry("Trade",strategy.long,when = Buysignal)
strategy.close("Trade",when = Sellsignal)
strategy.exit("Trade",when = Sellsignal2) ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

vitruvius's answer is correct, but specifically if you're trying to set `Sellsignal2` to equal `True` or `False`, then you don't need the `if`

Just assign it the result of evaluating `buytrend == 0` as in:

```
Sellsignal2 = buytrend == 0
```

Answer (score 0):

`Sellsignal2 = if buytrend == 0`

This is an unfinished statement. Your problem is there.